# How to set compiler options in Arduino Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino

I installed the Arduino Eclipse plugin, and created a new project. I want to compile my code with the `-std=c++11` option, but by default Eclipse does not use that option. Under Project Properties, for other C++ projects build options can be set in the C++ Build tab, but it is missing for my Arduino project. Is there any way to set the build options?

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed this plugin, and I wanted to do the same thing, in order to generate mixed C and Assembler listing. In summary, (This is for OSX, you will have to figure out the paths if you are on a different platform.)

1. Look in /Users/concunningham/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.23 for a file called platform.txt.
2. In there you will find a line like this:
   compiler.cpp.extra_flags=-Wa,-adhln -g > "$<".lst

You can see I added "-Wa,-adhln -g > "$<".lst" as extra options for the cpp compiler.

Now, this is key - restart Eclipse, clean the project in question, and rebuild. You should see your extra options take effect. Peep at the makefile to be sure.

Comment: I'd just like to re-emphasize the "Now, this is key - restart Eclipse" part. Changes to platform.txt are only picked up on startup, unfortunately.